# Why there is a convention of declaring default namespace/libraries in any programming language?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, programming-languages

Why don't any programming language load the default libraries like `stdio.h`, `iostream.h` or `using System`so that there declaration is avoided?

As these namespace/libraries are required in any program, why the compilers expect it to be declared by the user.

Do any programs exist without using namespace/headers? even if yes, whats wrong in loading a harmless default libraries?

I don't mean that .. I am lazy to write a line of code but it makes less sense (as per me) for a compiler to cry for declaration of so called **default** thingummies ending up in a compilation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there *are* programs which are written without the standard libraries.  For example, there are plenty of C programs running on embedded systems that don't provide `stdio.h`, since it doesn't make any sense on those platforms (in C, such environments are referred to as "freestanding", as opposed to the more usual "hosted").

Answer (score 2):

The “default” libraries are not “required in any program”, and indeed there are many cases where they are not even available (operating system kernel/drivers, microcontrollers, etc). And more in the mainstream, many high-level graphical programs use system-specific GUI/graphics libraries instead of standard I/O.

Answer (score 1):

For stdio.h/iostream(.h): the quick answer is that in the biggest part of your software, they are not needed (definitively not both).  Headless devices/servers should having a logging module instead and  GUI's don't always have a console to interface with.

Answer (score 1):

Many languages (especially scripting languages, and languages that carry a standard runtime as part of the language spec) *do* do this.

The trade-off is convenience versus software-engineering goodness.  The problem with opening namespaces by default is you end up with a lot of names being available immediately at the top level, which can cause name clashes and confusion, pollute Intellisense/autocompletion lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because libraries are external component of the language. If a day all library (or part of it) change headers, namespaces the language element don't change with them. The compiler checks the syntax and rules of programming language only.

Comment: That's not true in at least the cases of C and C++ - the `stdio.h` and `iostream` headers *are* part of the language specification. If their interface changes, the language has changed, by definition. Their exact contents are up to the implementation, of course.

Comment: The headers are part of ISO/ANSI C standard (that standardized which header files must be supplied) but there are not part of language. Some programs need to inculude i/o function and some not. The C principle is "economic use of resources".

Answer (score 0):

*To follow up on caf's answer.*

You need to tell the compiler about these headers/libraries so you do not have to include anything that you do not want. Because they are **not** needed in every program. Any programmer is able to write a library in c or c++ that does not depend on any runtime libraries. This ability makes it possible to write as lean software as possible, and save memory/diskspace/compile time/link time (pick what you need most). In low level languages you should only pay for what you need, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

There is name collision problem exist. As language standards developed, they provide more and more features, giving them more amd more names. And the probability that system name and name defined in user program raises. To avoid this, new features defined in modules which will not included if program not using it. As system libraries use many common usage words as its symbols (like `open`, `restricted`) problem is serious.

But explicit module inclusion is not only method for avoiding collisions. They also are: using "standard" namespace for system names (e.g. C++, `namespace std`), reserving names and name patterns (e.g. C, double underscores), allowed redefinition (e.g. Forth).